# Aggregation query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Node js using mongoose as ORM. I have set of documents like below

I want to calculate the average time for `createdAt` in ISO String(format) field in duration of hours on
grouping the category field. I have tried many ways to use aggregate but couldn't get the result.

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62dfc2cf25735e8b1b475ff1"
  },
  "numLikes": 0,
  "numViews": 0,
  "numShares": 0,
  "hasUserLiked": false,
  "title": "sample-broadcast",
  "description": "broadcast-dewscription",
  "projectId": {
    "$oid": "62d903a5dade1714382b27af"
  },
  "content": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62dfc2cf25735ee18d475ff2"
      },
      "downloadLink": "https://builder-broadcast-media.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/builder-broadcast-media/51daead4-1134-4921-a544-fea845f03d1c/uploadbroadcast/1658831544",
      "label": "lance-anderson-QdAAasrZhdk-unsplash (1).jpg",
      "contentType": "jpeg"
    }
  ],
  "delivery": "scheduleBroadcast",
  "category": "GENERAL_UPDATES",
  "groupId": "51daead4-1134-4921-a544-fea845f03d1c",
  "author": {
    "userId": "83314517-9326-430f-9c4e-8fedb050e6b0",
    "profilePic": "https://builder-broadcast-media.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/builder-broadcast-media/4f670832-dfd7-43ee-a6ad-e2f43f48df6a/uploadprofilepic/1658239806",
    "name": "Biswajit Rout"
  },
  "projectLogo": "https://builder-broadcast-media.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/builder-broadcast-media/4f670832-dfd7-43ee-a6ad-e2f43f48df6a/uploadcompanylogo%2A/1658239764",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1658831567577"
    }
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1658831567577"
    }
  },
  "__v": 0
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62dfebae25735e015f476dfb"
  },
  "numLikes": 0,
  "numViews": 0,
  "numShares": 0,
  "hasUserLiked": false,
  "title": "testing-broadcast",
  "description": "testing-description",
  "projectId": {
    "$oid": "62d903a5dade1714382b27af"
  },
  "content": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62dfebae25735e291c476dfc"
      },
      "downloadLink": "https://builder-broadcast-media.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/builder-broadcast-media/51daead4-1134-4921-a544-fea845f03d1c/projectimages0/1658842001",
      "label": "lance-anderson-QdAAasrZhdk-unsplash (1).jpg",
      "contentType": "jpeg"
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62dfebae25735e0321476dfd"
      },
      "downloadLink": "https://builder-broadcast-media.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/builder-broadcast-media/51daead4-1134-4921-a544-fea845f03d1c/projectimages1/1658842024",
      "label": "Get_Started_With_Smallpdf.pdf",
      "contentType": "pdf"
    }
  ],
  "delivery": "immediate",
  "link": "http://localhost:3000",
  "category": "GENERAL_UPDATES",
  "groupId": "51daead4-1134-4921-a544-fea845f03d1c",
  "author": {
    "userId": "83314517-9326-430f-9c4e-8fedb050e6b0",
    "profilePic": "https://builder-broadcast-media.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/builder-broadcast-media/4f670832-dfd7-43ee-a6ad-e2f43f48df6a/uploadprofilepic/1658239806",
    "name": "Biswajit Rout"
  },
  "projectLogo": "https://builder-broadcast-media.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/builder-broadcast-media/4f670832-dfd7-43ee-a6ad-e2f43f48df6a/uploadcompanylogo%2A/1658239764",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1658842030827"
    }
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1658842030827"
    }
  },
  "__v": 0
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62e144677fc76b0373f40152"
  },
  "numLikes": 0,
  "numViews": 0,
  "numShares": 0,
  "hasUserLiked": false,
  "title": "Broker Offer-1",
  "description": "50% off on the membership for early birds. \n\nOffer Applied to first fifty users only",
  "projectId": {
    "$oid": "62d903a5dade1714382b27af"
  },
  "content": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62e144677fc76b2b79f40153"
      },
      "downloadLink": "https://builder-broadcast-media.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/builder-broadcast-media/51daead4-1134-4921-a544-fea845f03d1c/projectimages0/1658930275",
      "label": "50-off-PNG-Picture.png",
      "contentType": "png"
    }
  ],
  "delivery": "immediate",
  "link": "",
  "category": "OFFER_BROKERS",
  "groupId": "51daead4-1134-4921-a544-fea845f03d1c",
  "author": {
    "userId": "83314517-9326-430f-9c4e-8fedb050e6b0",
    "profilePic": "https://builder-broadcast-media.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/builder-broadcast-media/4f670832-dfd7-43ee-a6ad-e2f43f48df6a/uploadprofilepic/1658239806",
    "name": "Biswajit Rout"
  },
  "projectLogo": "https://builder-broadcast-media.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/builder-broadcast-media/4f670832-dfd7-43ee-a6ad-e2f43f48df6a/uploadcompanylogo%2A/1658239764",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1658930279871"
    }
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1658930279871"
    }
  },
  "__v": 0
}]
```

My expected result should be like this

```
{
OFFER_BROKERS: 5 <hrs>,
GENERAL_UPDATES : 4 <hrs>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to convert milliseconds to real time and give it to orm

Comment: I need average time of  `createdAt` field documents grouping on basis of category.